# delete query not working java netbeans

Tags: java, sql, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a record in database  where if the username i typed is not admin i can delete it however its not working I think its the query  any idea thanks in advance.I am a newbie i been trying to figure it out ...

```
   String password = new String(oldPass.getPassword());
    String realpass = pw.getText();
    String us = userr.getText();
      user = us;

        System.out.println("ok");
        String query = "DELETE FROM user WHERE privilege = 'NOT ADMIN' +        username = '"+us+"'";
      try {
            Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            int r = st.executeUpdate(query);
            if (r != 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully deleted!", "Delete", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);

                login w = new login();
                w.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wait! something's wrong, please try again later.", "Ooopppss!", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }


      // TODO add        // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: Your query looks wrong in so many ways.  It has a plus symbol in it, and is `NOT ADMIN` really an actual privilege?  What database are you using?

Comment: im using php mysql even if i change the privilege as staff its still not deleted

Comment: `DELETE FROM user WHERE privilege = 'NOT ADMIN' AND username = 'lec'` ... use this syntax, do _not_ use a plus symbol

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a `PreparedStatement` to avoid an SQL injection attack.  This is just a learning exercise, but better to get into good habits now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing the AND or the Or operator depend on what are you trying to do here an example

`DELETE FROM user WHERE privilege = 'NOT ADMIN' AND user='user'`

Anyway I recommend you that instead use the string 'not admin' you create a new catalogue from privileges